# Overlying elements with position absolute

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two buttons with position absolute over a container with position absolute. It looks fine but when I resize the window the buttons display one over the other. How can I make the second button go to the next line if the margin is less than 10px?

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link href="one/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="map-canvas" class="jumbotron" style="position: relative"></div>

    <div class="jumbotron" style="position: relative"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 65%;">
        <a href="two/index.html" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" style="margin: 30px;">Two Explorers</a>
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 65%">
        <a href="one/index.html" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" style="margin: 30px;display:block ">One Explorer</a>
    </div>


    <div id="overlay" style="height: 50%;display: table;">
        <div class="container" style="display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;width:100%; text-align: center">
            <h1>The Demo of The Band to the Pole</h1>
            <h3>Select the version you want to see</h3>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

It's based on Bootstrap for the CSS. I added this id:

```
#map-canvas {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  margin:0px;
  background: transparent no-repeat 1 1;
}
#overlay {
  top:0px;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: .8;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Stop using inline `style`. It's a lot worse than you can imagine because, sooner or later you will need to modify your elements site-wide, at which point you'll start hunting for inline code, instead of modifying all of them from one line of code. 
   **You will *hate it***.
2. When two or more items are in relation to each other, don't use `position:absolute` on each of them. Instead, **place them as you like inside a parent (wrapper), and position the parent absolutely**.

If you need an actual example on your code, please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. (Add the CSS and the rest of the assets to your snippet, until we can experience the issue you are describing - generally speaking, when you need pictures to describe your problem on SO, you're *doing it wrong*).

---

Replace your buttons section with this:

```
<div class="overlayButtons">
  <a href="two/index.html" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Two Explorers</a>
  <a href="one/index.html" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">One Explorer</a>
</div>
```

and add this to your CSS:

```
.overlayButtons {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65%;
  padding: 30px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.overlayButtons .btn-lg {
  margin: 5px 10px;
  min-width: 150px;
}
```

Demo:

```css
body {margin: 0;}
#map-canvas {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  background: transparent no-repeat 1 1;
}
#overlay {
  top: 0;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: .8;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.overlayButtons {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65%;
  padding: 30px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.overlayButtons .btn-lg {
  margin: 5px 10px;
  min-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="map-canvas" class="jumbotron" style="position: relative"></div>
<div class="overlayButtons">
  <a href="two/index.html" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Two Explorers</a>
  <a href="one/index.html" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">One Explorer</a>
</div>
<div id="overlay" style="height: 50%;display: table;">
  <div class="container" style="display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;width:100%; text-align: center">
    <h1>The Demo of The Band to the Pole</h1>
    <h3>Select the version you want to see</h3>
  </div>

</div>
```

NOTE: your markup could use some improvements. Should you provide a link to a live version of it, I could make some suggestions.

Comment: Your snippet is missing quite a few assets. If you could provide a link to a live version of your code I could add them up.